# what a subclass inherits from a base class in C++?

Tags: c++, inheritance

I am trying to get through the concept of Inheritance (testing in C++). Here a quote from: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_(object-oriented_programming)

"In object-oriented programming (OOP), inheritance is a way to reuse code of existing objects, or to establish a subtype from an existing object, or both, depending upon programming language support"

Then I tested this code:

```
class Person
{
public:
    int ii;
    Person():ii(0){}
};
class Student : public Person
{
};
class Student1 : public Person
{
};
```

Then,

```
Person p;
Student s;
Student1 s1;
s.ii = 222;
p.ii = 333;
cout << s.ii << endl; // prints 222
cout << s1.ii << endl; // prints 0
cout << p.ii << endl; // prints 333
```

As shown in the results, each of the sub class has its own version of ii variable and each one the get the copy value from the base class. Therefore, when we changed one, it doesn't affect the others.

That's not what I got in mind at first place. I thought that when inheriting from a base class, all sub classes will inherit the same instance of attributes. Each sub class does not need to keep its own versions. And that can take the advantages of re-use and space saving.

Am I misunderstanding something? And if I am correct, is it true for other OOP languages, too?
(I know I can use static variable to reach my thought, but that's not what I am talking about)

Comment: A static variable is the way to go if you want all instances to share something.

Comment: You first have to understand what a class is: A class is a *type*. In C++, every object is of a certain type, and variables are objects. Inheritance is a way to organise *types*, not objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have three **instances** of the classes so they are independent. Meaning the subclasses don't have to declare `ii`. Think of the classes like templates (don't confuse them with the language construct template though) and then you create instances of them.

You wouldn't want all Persons to always have the same field values would you?

Having said that, you might be looking for (probably not/hopefully not) **static** variables.

Look up **instances** and **classes** in object orientation.

Answer (score 2):

You should treat a class not as an existing entity (well, at least in C++), but rather as a pattern that describes the behaviour of the class *instances* -- that is, individual objects which are created in some ways (in C++ -- using an explicit or implicit *constructor*).

The code `Student s;` describes `s` as an instance of class `Student`. Each of the fields in the class definition refers to the instance, not to the class itself.

You can however declare a *static* field, which will be shared between all the instances of `Student`, and even if there is no single instance created: you can see this as a *class* variable, as opposite to the *instance* variables.

So, back to your question: the subclass inherits the *pattern*: the fact of presence of some fields/methods in the instances. The values are however completely individual to the instances (with the exclusion of the class (static) variables).

The inheritance in C++ exists only on *class* level, and not on *instance* level.

Comment: I'm kind of intrigued now; in which languages is a class *not* a blueprint?

Comment: Ah, I haven't had any OOP experience with languages where it isn't.